# Using ruby and nokogiri to select ahrefs based on part of the URL

Tags: ruby, nokogiri

I have a document containing ahref links I want to extract. The link I want can be identified by part of  the url they link to. There are other links that are similar which I want to discard.

The urls  of the links I want are of the format

http://www.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.com/index.php?showtopic=44&hl=

I want to search for links containing  the h1=. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

You can just do a normal `find` on the document's set of A-tags.

```
document.search('a').find {|link| link['href'].include? 'h1='}
```